# How to create function to easily manipulate data multiple times?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying to create a function that I can use to easily manipulate/subset a larger dataset on multiple occasions, rather than having to repeat `dplyr` commands over and over again. Here is my example code.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Mock data.

data <- tibble(
  p = rep("Par_1", 40),
  v = c(rep("slo", 20), rep("mod", 20)),
  n = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10), rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10)),
  r = c(rep(800, 5), rep(100, 5), rep(800, 5), rep(100, 5),
        rep(800, 5), rep(100, 5), rep(800, 5), rep(100, 5)),
  x_tib_1 = runif(40, min = .100, max = .300),
  x_lum_1 = runif(40, min = .100, max = .300),
  x_tho_1 = runif(40, min = .100, max = .300),
  x_sen_1 = runif(40, min = .100, max = .300),
  x_ves_1 = runif(40, min = .100, max = .300),
)

# Function to manipulate data.

test_function <- function(x, y, z){
  
  output <- data %>%
    filter(v == x, n == y, r == z) %>%
    select(p, ifelse(z == 800, matches("tib | lum | tho"),
                                  c(5:9))) %>% # i.e. x_tib_1:x_ves_1.
    group_by(p) %>%
    summarise_all(list(mean)) %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 3)) # Would usally have na.rm = TRUE here to account for NA.
  
  return(output)
}

# Test function.

test <- test_function("slo", 1, 800)
```

I'm aiming to input values for `data$v`, `data$n`, `data$r` in `test_function` that I want to use to filter the dataset. Then, I only want to select certain columns based on the value of `z` in `test_function` (800 or 100). I don't know if I'm using `dplyr::matches` correctly here or not, but if `z` is 800, I only want to select `p`, `x_tib_1`, `x_lum_1` and `x_tho_1`.

The code doesn't work currently, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifelse` requires all arguments to be equal length.  We can use `if/else`.  In addition, there are spaces in the regex pattern used in `matches` i.e. `"tib | lum | tho"` which doesn't exist in the column name.

```
test_function <- function(data, x, y, z){
  
   data %>%
    filter(v == x, n == y, r == z) %>%
    select(p, if(z == 800) matches("tib|lum|tho") else 
                                  c(5:9))  %>%
   group_by(p) %>%
   summarise_all(list(mean)) %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 3)) #
}
```

-testing

```
> test_function(data, "slo", 1, 800)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  p     x_tib_1 x_lum_1 x_tho_1
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Par_1   0.188   0.182   0.229
>  test_function(data, "slo", 1, 100)
# A tibble: 1 x 6
  p     x_tib_1 x_lum_1 x_tho_1 x_sen_1 x_ves_1
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Par_1    0.22   0.226   0.182   0.214   0.225
```